# Debugger is skipping many lines of code in library project

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, mstest

I am unit testing some classes in a C# library project.

I set breakpoints in my library code which are hit, but these are the *only* lines which are hit. When I try to step through the code, it just jumps from breakpoint to breakpoint.

I was looking at: [How to debug (step into) a class library referenced in my project and has .pdb and source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086914/how-to-debug-step-into-a-class-library-referenced-in-my-project-and-has-pdb-a)

- I'm building my unit test project and the library in debug mode
- I already un-ticked "just my code" in the debug settings.
- The Modules window shows "symbols loaded" for both modules and the symbol files are both in the binary's built path
- Both projects are part of my solution

What else can I try? I haven't seen this before, I'm used to C# debugging being rock-solid compared to C++!

Comment: Did you disable "Optimize code" for the library? It's under Project Properties -> Build -> General. Although often that causes erratic jumping instead of the seemingly predictable kind that you are seeing, but who knows.

Comment: Checked that :) I'm wondering if some build dependencies are not set correctly so far...

Comment: Only time I've ever had lines skip and even blank lines execute was when I was referencing a DLL (not a project) and sitting next to it was an out of date PDB file. Double check you have the project referenced or you have an up to date PDB.